# htaccess url rewriting 2 get vars

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Ok .htaccess url rewriting.. I really don't get it. 
I need a rewriterule to server-translate http://domain.com/?list&cat=1 to
http://domain.com/list/1/ ..

Can't figure out how this exactly works.
Who can help :)?

Can somebody give me a nice tutorial or something and some help with my question?

Thank you & kind regards,

SantaWhereClause Jordy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)/$ index.php?ond=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?ond=$1 [NC]
```

This was the solution.

Needed request_filename to keep the images, js, css etc and edited
every url too http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/etc/etc/etc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you use substituition patterns for that

example: http://domain.com/list/1

rewrite to: http://domain.com/index.php?list=&cat=1

rewrite rule:
    `RewriteRule /list/([0-9]+) /index.php?list&cat=$1`

the `()` around `[0-9]+` bind to `$1` if you have other `()` they will bind to `$2`, `$3`, etc.

if you want the other way around just adapt the regular expression, but usualy you want this way.

Comment: Doesn't did the job for me... I thought you ment to say:
    RewriteRule /list/([0-9]+) /index.php?ond=list&cat=$1 

You forgot the ond= in the first part.. but this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=(.*)

RewriteRule ^list /list/%1

(I think!)